# how to remove a variable in conjunction of functions in the loop?

Tags: python-3.x, python

```
def wpath():
    defpath = '/home/me/documents/'
    os.chdir(defpath)
    path = str(input("would you like to change current working directory? [y/yes] if you want"))
    if path == 'yes' or path == 'y':
        while True:
            try:
                os.chdir(input('Enter new path! \n'))
                break
            except OSError:
                print('\nno such directory! Try again!')
    else:
        pass
    src()


def src():
    global d
    d = {}
    n = 0
    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if re.search('.?\.(txt|csv|log)', file):
            n += 1
            print(n, file)
            d[n] = file
    if len(d) == 0:
        del d
        wpath()

wpath()

val = int(input('Enter number of file\n'))
if val in d:
    source = d[val]
```

After I published my post, I realized my mistake. Thanks.
Now the code works. I've corrected the code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You invoke `del d` only if `len(d) == 0`. Does that happen? Can you insert a `print` call into that branch and see if `del` is actually called?

That said, `del d` is a code smell. I'm 99.99% sure you don't really need to use it here. Can you explain what it is you're trying to do exactly?

Besides that, why do you need `d` as a dictionary, if you only add consecutive numeric keys to it? Would it not be better to have a list and `append` to it instead?

Comment: Eli "That said, del d is a code smell. I'm 99.99% sure you don't really need to use it here. Can you explain what it is you're trying to do exactly?"                                              

I want to delete an empty variable 'd', if in the directory there is no needed files(txt,log)

Comment: @werwolf_x: why do you want to delete it?

Comment: I think this is the easiest option. what do you suggest?

Comment: @werwolf_x: deleting a variable in Python is rarely useful. you could assign it to {} again